# Are there automated theorem provers for constructive logics? What strategy do they use?

Tags: software-request, automated-theorem-proving, constructive

I know of a handful of automated theorem provers for classical first-order logic such as [Vampire](https://vprover.github.io/index.html) ([source code](https://github.com/vprover/vampire)).

Internally, I think most of these provers work by translating premises and the negated goal into disjunctions of literals and then applying [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#Resolution_in_first_order_logic). This also requires [Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form#How_Skolemization_works) as a preprocessing step, which removes existential quantifiers in the prenex of a wff and adds new function symbols to the language. Here's a link to the [the Skolemization implementation in Vampire](https://github.com/vprover/vampire/blob/0de3f9a221e8dfba39e197192effae2107b65ef7/Shell/Skolem.cpp).

This technique will not work in a constructive setting. Negating the goal, converting to negative normal form and then prenex normal form is not constructively valid.

What automated theorem provers for intuitionistic first-order logic are there (whether they're capable of emitting proof terms or not)? If there are any, broadly speaking, what strategy do they use?

Comment: @GuyCoder why not automatic-theorem-proving?

Comment: How is disjunction elimination not constructively valid? Coq accepts it without any axioms:`Theorem disj_elim (A B : Prop) (hAorB : A \/ B) (hNotA : ~A): B.
Proof.
  destruct hAorB as [hA | hB].
  - contradiction (hNotA hA).
  - exact hB.
Qed.`

Comment: @NieDzejkob, You're totally right. This inference is valid in IPC. Fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`firstorder` tactic](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/logic.html#coq:tacn.firstorder) in Coq is an "experimental extension of tauto to first-order reasoning."  The  [`tauto` tactic](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/automatic-tactics/logic.html#coq:tacn.tauto) "implements a decision procedure for intuitionistic propositional calculus based on the contraction-free sequent calculi LJT* of Roy Dyckhoff [[Dyc92]](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/zebibliography.html#dyc92)".  Perhaps one of the Coq developers can speak to the theory behind `firstorder`.

These tactics do not rely on classical axioms, and do generate proof terms.

Comment: LJT* is also the theory behind tools like Djinn (https://github.com/augustss/djinn) in Haskell and Hezarfen (https://github.com/joom/hezarfen) in Idris